# error using bool variable in android ndk

Tags: android, c, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I'm having trouble using bool as a type compiling with ndk-build:

```
bool test = true;
```

error:

> 48: error: 'bool' undeclared (first
>   use in this function)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`bool` is not a built-in type in C. You need to `#include <stdbool.h>` to get it.